# system.typeinitializationexception' occurred in mscorlib.dll Visual Studio 2015 C#

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2015, mscorlib, typeinitializeexception

So I cannot find a solution to this problem: I am using a .DLL Library which I need to interact with an external device, but when I'm using the .DLL (bold line in code example) I get the error: system.typeinitializationexception' occurred in mscorlib.dll

The .DLL should be correctly implemented through properties in the solution explorer of Visual Studio 2015 and the code works with no problem on 2 different laptops, but this error occurs when I try to use it on my desktop - where I need it to be functional.

### Code example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using Inomed;
using Inomed.Software.CommonLib.NeurostimInterface;

namespace Server3
{
    static class Program
    {
        **public static Neurostim_interface myNeuro = new Neurostim_interface();**


        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

---

Error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information:

> The type initializer for 'Server3.Program' threw an exception. Debug:
>   [...] 'Server3.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Server3.vshost.exe):
>   Loaded 'c:\users\bo\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\Server3\Server3\bin\Debug\Neurostimulator_HID_DLL.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled.
>       Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in Neurostimulator_HID_DLL.dll
>       The program '[11160] Server3.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Is the dll in your `\bin\` folder after you compile?

Comment: Yes it appears both in the debug and release folder after compiling them

Comment: Update: When breaking the exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' the new error explains 

"Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in Neurostimulator_HID_DLL.dll

Additional information: Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)"

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters, but what is `Embed Interop Types` set to when viewing the properties of the referenced Dll?

Comment: It is set to false, but setting it to true gave the error CS1759: Cannot embed interop types from assembly 'Neurostimulator_HID_DLL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it is missing either the 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ImportedFromTypeLibAttribute' attribute or the 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.PrimaryInteropAssemblyAttribute' attribute

Comment: Update 2: So, when the device (which the .dll is used for) is connected to this PC, the program is able to execute. So I guess it has something to do with it crashing when it cannot connect. But just to clairy, this does not happen on the other laptops